# CanActivate guard in angular routing without repeating "CanActivate " property

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards, angular-guards

I want to use the canActivate guard in routing without repeating the

> canActivate: [AuthGuard],

code like below

```
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/app/core/guards/auth.guard';
 
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '', data: { title: 'Users' },
  children: [
    {
          path: 'createuser',
          canActivate: [AuthGuard],
          component: UserComponent,
          data: { title: 'Create User' }
        },
     {
          path: 'updateuser',
          canActivate: [AuthGuard],
          component: UpdateUserComponent,
          data: { title: 'Update User' }
        },
  ]
}];
```

Comment: Refer this official [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild)

Comment: I want to use canActivate in the main path also "/Users"

Answer (score 0):

In your example you can use [canActivateChild](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild)

```
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/app/core/guards/auth.guard';
 
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '', data: { title: 'Users' },
  canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    {
          path: 'createuser',
          component: UserComponent,
          data: { title: 'Create User' }
        },
     {
          path: 'updateuser',
          component: UpdateUserComponent,
          data: { title: 'Update User' }
        },
  ]
}];
```

so this auth guard will be applied to all children

Comment: I want to use canActivate in the main path also "/Users"

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for CanActivateChild, it lets you specify a guard for all child routes

```
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/app/core/guards/auth.guard';
 
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '', data: { title: 'Users' }, canActivateChild: [AuthGuard]
  children: [
    {
          path: 'createuser',
          component: UserComponent,
          data: { title: 'Create User' }
        },
     {
          path: 'updateuser',
          component: UpdateUserComponent,
          data: { title: 'Update User' }
        },
  ]
}];
```

Tooked from: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild

Comment: I want to use canActivate in the main path also "/Users"